# Sabre AirTicketLLSRQ error: PNR HAS BEEN UPDATED-IGN AND RETRY-0049

Tags: web-services, soap, sabre

I'm trying to do Issue Air Ticket workflow, but `AirTicketLLSRQ` returns error:

```
PNR HAS BEEN UPDATED-IGN AND RETRY-0049
```

Before this, I'm creating PNR with `PassengerDetailsRQ` method.

Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Header>
        <MessageHeader xmlns="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
            <From>
                <PartyId>WebServiceClient</PartyId>
            </From>
            <To>
                <PartyId>WebServiceSupplier</PartyId>
            </To>
            <CPAId>4PFI</CPAId>
            <ConversationId>SWS-Test-4PFI</ConversationId>
            <Service>PassengerDetails</Service>
            <Action>PassengerDetailsRQ</Action>
            <MessageData>
                <MessageId>9314594d-6c40-406b-9029-b887b13906b6</MessageId>
                <Timestamp>2017-07-11T08:57:38Z</Timestamp>
            </MessageData>
        </MessageHeader>
        <Security xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
            <BinarySecurityToken>
                Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/CERTG!ICESMSLB\/CRT.LB!-3255696707179766905!1188118!0
            </BinarySecurityToken>
        </Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <PassengerDetailsRQ xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_3" version="3.3.0" IgnoreOnError="false"
                            HaltOnError="false">
            <PostProcessing IgnoreAfter="false" RedisplayReservation="true">
                <EndTransactionRQ>
                    <EndTransaction Ind="true">
                        <Email Ind="true">
                            <Itinerary Ind="true">
                                <PDF Ind="true"/>
                                <Segment Number="1"/>
                            </Itinerary>
                        </Email>
                    </EndTransaction>
                    <Source ReceivedFrom="TEST"/>
                </EndTransactionRQ>
            </PostProcessing>
            <SpecialReqDetails>
                <AddRemarkRQ>
                    <RemarkInfo>
                        <Remark Code="H" SegmentNumber="1" Type="General">
                            <Text>TEXT</Text>
                        </Remark>
                    </RemarkInfo>
                </AddRemarkRQ>
                <SpecialServiceRQ>
                    <SpecialServiceInfo>
                        <AdvancePassenger SegmentNumber="A">
                            <!--  2. a legal LLS request  -->
                            <Document ExpirationDate="2018-05-26" Number="1234567890" Type="P">
                                <IssueCountry>FR</IssueCountry>
                                <NationalityCountry>FR</NationalityCountry>
                            </Document>
                            <PersonName DateOfBirth="1980-12-02" Gender="M" NameNumber="1.1" DocumentHolder="true">
                                <GivenName>JAMES</GivenName>
                                <MiddleName>MALCOLM</MiddleName>
                                <Surname>GREEN</Surname>
                            </PersonName>
                            <VendorPrefs>
                                <Airline Hosted="false"/>
                            </VendorPrefs>
                        </AdvancePassenger>
                        <SecureFlight SegmentNumber="A">
                            <PersonName DateOfBirth="1980-12-02" Gender="M" NameNumber="1.1">
                                <GivenName>JAMES</GivenName>
                                <Surname>GREEN</Surname>
                            </PersonName>
                        </SecureFlight>
                    </SpecialServiceInfo>
                </SpecialServiceRQ>
            </SpecialReqDetails>
            <TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ>
                <AgencyInfo>
                    <Address>
                        <AddressLine>SABRE TRAVEL</AddressLine>
                        <CityName>SOUTHLAKE</CityName>
                        <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
                        <PostalCode>76092</PostalCode>
                        <StateCountyProv StateCode="TX"/>
                        <StreetNmbr>3150 SABRE DRIVE</StreetNmbr>
                        <VendorPrefs>
                            <Airline Hosted="true"/>
                        </VendorPrefs>
                    </Address>
                    <Ticketing TicketType="7T-"/>
                </AgencyInfo>
                <CustomerInfo>
                    <ContactNumbers>
                        <ContactNumber Phone="817-555-1212" PhoneUseType="A"/>
                    </ContactNumbers>
                    <Email Address="yury.patrin@gmail.com" NameNumber="1.1"/>
                    <PersonName NameNumber="1.1">
                        <GivenName>JAMES</GivenName>
                        <Surname>GREEN</Surname>
                    </PersonName>
                </CustomerInfo>
            </TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ>
        </PassengerDetailsRQ>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap-env:Header>
        <eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" eb:version="1.0" soap-env:mustUnderstand="1">
            <eb:From>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">WebServiceSupplier</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:From>
            <eb:To>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">WebServiceClient</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:To>
            <eb:CPAId>4PFI</eb:CPAId>
            <eb:ConversationId>SWS-Test-4PFI</eb:ConversationId>
            <eb:Service>PassengerDetails</eb:Service>
            <eb:Action>PassengerDetailsRS</eb:Action>
            <eb:MessageData>
                <eb:MessageId>1i9226s68</eb:MessageId>
                <eb:Timestamp>2017-07-11T08:50:23</eb:Timestamp>
                <eb:RefToMessageId>9314594d-6c40-406b-9029-b887b13906b6</eb:RefToMessageId>
            </eb:MessageData>
        </eb:MessageHeader>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">
                Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/CERTG!ICESMSLB\/CRT.LB!-3255696707179766905!1188118!0
            </wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap-env:Header>
    <soap-env:Body>
        <PassengerDetailsRS xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_3">
            <ApplicationResults xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/STL_Payload/v02_01" status="Complete">
                <Success timeStamp="2017-07-11T03:50:23.635-05:00"/>
                <Warning type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2017-07-11T03:50:23.469-05:00">
                    <SystemSpecificResults>
                        <Message code="WARN.SWS.HOST.WARNING_RESPONSE">EndTransactionLLSRQ: TTY REQ PEND</Message>
                    </SystemSpecificResults>
                </Warning>
            </ApplicationResults>
            <ItineraryRef ID="PGAAHT"/>
            <TravelItineraryReadRS>
                <TravelItinerary>
                    <CustomerInfo>
                        <Address>
                            <AddressLine type="N">SABRE TRAVEL</AddressLine>
                            <AddressLine type="A">3150 SABRE DRIVE</AddressLine>
                            <AddressLine type="C">SOUTHLAKE, TX US</AddressLine>
                            <AddressLine type="Z">76092</AddressLine>
                        </Address>
                        <ContactNumbers>
                            <ContactNumber LocationCode="IEV" Phone="817-555-1212-A" RPH="001"/>
                        </ContactNumbers>
                        <PersonName NameNumber="01.01" RPH="1" WithInfant="false">
                            <Email>YURY.PATRIN@GMAIL.COM</Email>
                            <GivenName>JAMES</GivenName>
                            <Surname>GREEN</Surname>
                        </PersonName>
                    </CustomerInfo>
                    <ItineraryInfo>
                        <ReservationItems>
                            <Item RPH="1">
                                <FlightSegment AirMilesFlown="0484" ArrivalDateTime="08-13T08:45" DayOfWeekInd="7" DepartureDateTime="2017-08-13T07:05" ElapsedTime="01.40" FlightNumber="0465" IsPast="false" NumberInParty="01" ResBookDesigCode="Y" SegmentNumber="0001" SmokingAllowed="false" SpecialMeal="false" Status="HK" StopQuantity="00" eTicket="false">
                                    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="HKG" Terminal="TERMINAL 1" TerminalCode="1"/>
                                    <Equipment AirEquipType="773"/>
                                    <MarketingAirline Code="CX" FlightNumber="0465"/>
                                    <Meal Code="B"/>
                                    <OriginLocation LocationCode="TPE" Terminal="TERMINAL 1" TerminalCode="1"/>
                                    <SupplierRef ID="DCCX"/>
                                    <UpdatedArrivalTime>08-13T08:45</UpdatedArrivalTime>
                                    <UpdatedDepartureTime>08-13T07:05</UpdatedDepartureTime>
                                </FlightSegment>
                            </Item>
                        </ReservationItems>
                        <Ticketing RPH="01" TicketTimeLimit="T-"/>
                    </ItineraryInfo>
                    <ItineraryRef AirExtras="false" ID="PGAAHT" InhibitCode="U" PartitionID="AA" PrimeHostID="1S">
                        <Source AAA_PseudoCityCode="4PFI" CreateDateTime="2017-07-11T03:50" CreationAgent="AWS" HomePseudoCityCode="4PFI" LastUpdateDateTime="2017-07-11T03:50" PseudoCityCode="4PFI" ReceivedFrom="TEST" SequenceNumber="1"/>
                    </ItineraryRef>
                    <RemarkInfo>
                        <Remark RPH="001" Type="General">
                            <Text>TEXT</Text>
                        </Remark>
                    </RemarkInfo>
                    <SpecialServiceInfo RPH="001" Type="GFX">
                        <Service SSR_Code="SSR" SSR_Type="DOCS">
                            <Airline Code="CX"/>
                            <PersonName NameNumber="01.01">GREEN/JAMES</PersonName>
                            <Text>
                                HK1/P/FR/1234567890/FR/02DEC1980/M/26MAY2018/GREEN/JAMES/MALCOLM/H
                            </Text>
                        </Service>
                    </SpecialServiceInfo>
                </TravelItinerary>
            </TravelItineraryReadRS>
        </PassengerDetailsRS>
    </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

After this request I recieved booking confirmation on my email. Then, I do `DesignatePrinterLLSRQ` and `TravelItineraryReadRQ`.

`TravelItineraryReadRQ` Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Header>
        <MessageHeader xmlns="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
            <From>
                <PartyId>WebServiceClient</PartyId>
            </From>
            <To>
                <PartyId>WebServiceSupplier</PartyId>
            </To>
            <CPAId>4PFI</CPAId>
            <ConversationId>SWS-Test-4PFI</ConversationId>
            <Service>TravelItineraryRead</Service>
            <Action>TravelItineraryReadRQ</Action>
            <MessageData>
                <MessageId>9314594d-6c40-406b-9029-b887b13906b6</MessageId>
                <Timestamp>2017-07-11T08:36:19Z</Timestamp>
            </MessageData>
        </MessageHeader>
        <Security xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
            <BinarySecurityToken>
                Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/CERTG!ICESMSLB\/CRT.LB!-3255700571383677304!1140614!0
            </BinarySecurityToken>
        </Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <TravelItineraryReadRQ xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/res/tir/v3_9"
                               xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                               xmlns:dd="http://webservices.sabre.com/dd2" Version="3.9.0">
            <MessagingDetails>
                <SubjectAreas>
                    <SubjectArea>FULL</SubjectArea>
                </SubjectAreas>
            </MessagingDetails>
            <UniqueID ID=""/>
            <EchoToken/>
        </TravelItineraryReadRQ>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap-env:Header>
        <eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" eb:version="1.0"
                          soap-env:mustUnderstand="1">
            <eb:From>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">WebServiceSupplier</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:From>
            <eb:To>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">WebServiceClient</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:To>
            <eb:CPAId>4PFI</eb:CPAId>
            <eb:ConversationId>SWS-Test-4PFI</eb:ConversationId>
            <eb:Service>TravelItineraryRead</eb:Service>
            <eb:Action>TravelItineraryReadRS</eb:Action>
            <eb:MessageData>
                <eb:MessageId>2506522311129290610</eb:MessageId>
                <eb:Timestamp>2017-07-11T08:38:33</eb:Timestamp>
                <eb:RefToMessageId>9314594d-6c40-406b-9029-b887b13906b6</eb:RefToMessageId>
            </eb:MessageData>
        </eb:MessageHeader>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">
                Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/CERTG!ICESMSLB\/CRT.LB!-3255700571383677304!1140614!0
            </wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap-env:Header>
    <soap-env:Body>
        <tir39:TravelItineraryReadRS xmlns:tir39="http://services.sabre.com/res/tir/v3_9"
                                     xmlns:or8="http://services.sabre.com/res/or/v1_8"
                                     xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01"
                                     xmlns:or19="http://services.sabre.com/res/or/v1_9" Version="3.9.0">
            <stl:ApplicationResults status="Complete">
                <stl:Success timeStamp="2017-07-11T03:38:33.392-05:00"/>
            </stl:ApplicationResults>
            <tir39:TravelItinerary>
                <tir39:CustomerInfo>
                    <tir39:Address>
                        <tir39:AddressLine Id="8" type="N">SABRE TRAVEL</tir39:AddressLine>
                        <tir39:AddressLine Id="9" type="A">3150 SABRE DRIVE</tir39:AddressLine>
                        <tir39:AddressLine Id="10" type="C">SOUTHLAKE, TX US</tir39:AddressLine>
                        <tir39:AddressLine Id="11" type="Z">76092</tir39:AddressLine>
                    </tir39:Address>
                    <tir39:ContactNumbers>
                        <tir39:ContactNumber LocationCode="IEV" Phone="817-555-1212-A" RPH="001" Id="7"/>
                    </tir39:ContactNumbers>
                    <tir39:PersonName WithInfant="false" NameNumber="01.01" RPH="1" elementId="pnr-4.1">
                        <tir39:Email Id="6">YURY.PATRIN@GMAIL.COM</tir39:Email>
                        <tir39:GivenName>JAMES</tir39:GivenName>
                        <tir39:Surname>GREEN</tir39:Surname>
                    </tir39:PersonName>
                </tir39:CustomerInfo>
                <tir39:ItineraryInfo>
                    <tir39:ReservationItems>
                        <tir39:Item RPH="1">
                            <tir39:FlightSegment AirMilesFlown="0484" ArrivalDateTime="08-13T08:45" DayOfWeekInd="7"
                                                 DepartureDateTime="2017-08-13T07:05"
                                                 SegmentBookedDate="2017-07-11T03:34:00" ElapsedTime="01.40"
                                                 eTicket="false" FlightNumber="0465" NumberInParty="01"
                                                 ResBookDesigCode="Y" SegmentNumber="0001" SmokingAllowed="false"
                                                 SpecialMeal="false" Status="HK" StopQuantity="00" IsPast="false"
                                                 CodeShare="false" Id="3">
                                <tir39:DestinationLocation LocationCode="HKG" Terminal="TERMINAL 1" TerminalCode="1"/>
                                <tir39:Equipment AirEquipType="773"/>
                                <tir39:MarketingAirline Code="CX" FlightNumber="0465">
                                    <tir39:Banner>MARKETED BY CATHAY PACIFIC AIRWAYS</tir39:Banner>
                                </tir39:MarketingAirline>
                                <tir39:Meal Code="B"/>
                                <tir39:OperatingAirline Code="CX" FlightNumber="0465" ResBookDesigCode="Y">
                                    <tir39:Banner>OPERATED BY CATHAY PACIFIC AIRWAYS</tir39:Banner>
                                </tir39:OperatingAirline>
                                <tir39:OperatingAirlinePricing Code="CX"/>
                                <tir39:DisclosureCarrier Code="CX" DOT="false">
                                    <tir39:Banner>CATHAY PACIFIC AIRWAYS</tir39:Banner>
                                </tir39:DisclosureCarrier>
                                <tir39:OriginLocation LocationCode="TPE" Terminal="TERMINAL 1" TerminalCode="1"/>
                                <tir39:SupplierRef ID="DCCX"/>
                                <tir39:UpdatedArrivalTime>08-13T08:45</tir39:UpdatedArrivalTime>
                                <tir39:UpdatedDepartureTime>08-13T07:05</tir39:UpdatedDepartureTime>
                            </tir39:FlightSegment>
                        </tir39:Item>
                    </tir39:ReservationItems>
                    <tir39:Ticketing RPH="01" TicketTimeLimit="T-"/>
                </tir39:ItineraryInfo>
                <tir39:ItineraryRef AirExtras="false" ID="UJUDSY" InhibitCode="U" PartitionID="AA" PrimeHostID="1S">
                    <tir39:Source AAA_PseudoCityCode="4PFI" CreateDateTime="2017-07-11T03:34" CreationAgent="AWS"
                                  HomePseudoCityCode="4PFI" PseudoCityCode="4PFI" ReceivedFrom="TEST"
                                  LastUpdateDateTime="2017-07-11T03:34" SequenceNumber="1"/>
                </tir39:ItineraryRef>
                <tir39:RemarkInfo>
                    <tir39:Remark RPH="001" Type="General" Id="14">
                        <tir39:Text>TEXT</tir39:Text>
                    </tir39:Remark>
                </tir39:RemarkInfo>
                <tir39:SpecialServiceInfo RPH="001" Type="GFX" Id="12">
                    <tir39:Service SSR_Code="SSR" SSR_Type="DOCS">
                        <tir39:Airline Code="CX"/>
                        <tir39:PersonName NameNumber="01.01">GREEN/JAMES</tir39:PersonName>
                        <tir39:Text>
                            HK1/P/FR/1234567890/FR/02DEC1980/M/26MAY2018/GREEN/JAMES/MALCOLM/H
                        </tir39:Text>
                    </tir39:Service>
                </tir39:SpecialServiceInfo>
                <tir39:SpecialServiceInfo RPH="002" Type="GFX" Id="13">
                    <tir39:Service SSR_Code="SSR" SSR_Type="DOCS">
                        <tir39:Airline Code="CX"/>
                        <tir39:PersonName NameNumber="01.01">GREEN/JAMES</tir39:PersonName>
                        <tir39:Text>HK1/DB/02DEC1980/M/GREEN/JAMES</tir39:Text>
                    </tir39:Service>
                </tir39:SpecialServiceInfo>
            </tir39:TravelItinerary>
        </tir39:TravelItineraryReadRS>
    </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

And then I do `AirTicketLLSRQ`.

Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Header>
        <MessageHeader xmlns="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
            <From>
                <PartyId>WebServiceClient</PartyId>
            </From>
            <To>
                <PartyId>WebServiceSupplier</PartyId>
            </To>
            <CPAId>4PFI</CPAId>
            <ConversationId>SWS-Test-4PFI</ConversationId>
            <Service>AirTicketRQ</Service>
            <Action>AirTicketLLSRQ</Action>
            <MessageData>
                <MessageId>9314594d-6c40-406b-9029-b887b13906b6</MessageId>
                <Timestamp>2017-07-11T08:39:43Z</Timestamp>
            </MessageData>
        </MessageHeader>
        <Security xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
            <BinarySecurityToken>
                Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/CERTG!ICESMSLB\/CRT.LB!-3255700571383677304!1140614!0
            </BinarySecurityToken>
        </Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <AirTicketRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" NumResponses="1" Version="2.10.0"
                     ReturnHostCommand="true">
            <OptionalQualifiers>
                <FlightQualifiers>
                    <VendorPrefs>
                        <Airline Code="CX"/>
                    </VendorPrefs>
                </FlightQualifiers>
                <MiscQualifiers>
                    <Ticket Type="ETR"/>
                </MiscQualifiers>
                <PricingQualifiers>
                    <PriceQuote>
                        <Record Number="1"/>
                    </PriceQuote>
                </PricingQualifiers>
            </OptionalQualifiers>
        </AirTicketRQ>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap-env:Header>
        <eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" eb:version="1.0"
                          soap-env:mustUnderstand="1">
            <eb:From>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">WebServiceSupplier</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:From>
            <eb:To>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">WebServiceClient</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:To>
            <eb:CPAId>4PFI</eb:CPAId>
            <eb:ConversationId>SWS-Test-4PFI</eb:ConversationId>
            <eb:Service>AirTicketRQ</eb:Service>
            <eb:Action>AirTicketLLSRS</eb:Action>
            <eb:MessageData>
                <eb:MessageId>393675312556970611</eb:MessageId>
                <eb:Timestamp>2017-07-11T08:40:56</eb:Timestamp>
                <eb:RefToMessageId>9314594d-6c40-406b-9029-b887b13906b6</eb:RefToMessageId>
            </eb:MessageData>
        </eb:MessageHeader>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">
                Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/CERTG!ICESMSLB\/CRT.LB!-3255700571383677304!1140614!0
            </wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap-env:Header>
    <soap-env:Body>
        <AirTicketRS xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01"
                     Version="2.10.0">
            <stl:ApplicationResults status="NotProcessed">
                <stl:Error type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2017-07-11T03:40:56-05:00">
                    <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                        <stl:HostCommand LNIATA="757110">W¥PQ1¥ETR¥ACX</stl:HostCommand>
                        <stl:Message>PNR HAS BEEN UPDATED-IGN AND RETRY-0049</stl:Message>
                        <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</stl:ShortText>
                    </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                </stl:Error>
            </stl:ApplicationResults>
        </AirTicketRS>
    </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

How can I fix this error? Maybe I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sabre is launching a new Orchestrated AirTicketRQ service that will automate and simplify many of these items, and much much more magic. If you are interested, please let us know...

Comment: Yes, it very interested for me. When I going to doc (https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/air/fulfill/orchestrated_air_ticket), sabre dev center say me "You don’t have access to see this page"

Comment: Will reach out available in the next few weeks for Beta testing.

Comment: Enhanced AirTicket unfortunately doesn't handle `PNR HAS BEEN UPDATED-IGN AND RETRY` & `CARRIER NOT RESPONDING-RETRY LATER`. I ended implementing own retry with delays logic ((

Answer (score 2):

What you encountered is quite a normal situation (but unwanted).

Solution to this is to run (but only after you detect `PNR HAS BEEN UPDATED-IGN AND RETRY` error)

- ignore command
- rerun AirTicketRQ (exactly the same that failed in the first run)

As far as Ignore command is concerned what you should know is that it will ignore (cancel) all your PNR changes since the last successful EndTransactionRQ, so it's best to have everything saved before AirTicketRQ is expected to be run

Example of ignore command (`IR` in `HostCommand` will trigger ignore transaction) :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <ns4:MessageHeader xmlns:ns8="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:ns7="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2002/11" xmlns:ns6="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:ns5="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ns4="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
      <ns4:ConversationId> CONVERSATION_ID </ns4:ConversationId>
      <ns4:From>
        <ns4:PartyId ns4:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01"> PARTY_ID_FROM </ns4:PartyId>
        <ns4:Role></ns4:Role>
      </ns4:From>
      <ns4:To>
        <ns4:PartyId ns4:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01"> PARTY_ID_TO </ns4:PartyId>
        <ns4:Role></ns4:Role>
      </ns4:To>
      <ns4:CPAId>GF</ns4:CPAId>
      <ns4:Service ns4:type="OTA"></ns4:Service>
      <ns4:Action>SabreCommandLLSRQ</ns4:Action>
    </ns4:MessageHeader>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
      <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary"> BOOKING_PROVIDER_SESSION </wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <SabreCommandLLSRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2003/07" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" TimeStamp="2014-03-04T14:00:00" Version="1.8.1">
      <Request Output="SCREEN" CDATA="true">
        <HostCommand>IR</HostCommand>
      </Request>
    </SabreCommandLLSRQ>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```